# 'AppContext' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.AppContext' and '<usernamespace>.AppContext'

Tags: .net-4.5, .net-framework-version, .net-4.6

- I had Visual Studio 2013 and my code was working fine.
- Installed Visual Studio 2015 community edition and code stopped working.
- Uninstalled Visual Studio 2015, still code doesn't work.

I read, on installing Visual Studio 2015, the content of folder location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 is changed. i.e. "in-place upgrade of .net 4.6"

- looked at mscorlib.dll via ilspy, the class System.AppContext is not present on my friend's system who has not upgraded yet to .net4.6
- My system, mscorlib.dll, class System.AppContext is present

I need to go back to previous version of mscorlib.dll, how to do it? 
System doesn't allow a file replace.

I should mention, the code compiles. But throws this error on runtime.

Comment: Found a blog of great people, but couldn't see the solution http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of a name clash with a class that Microsoft added to the System namespace called AppContext. As it turns out, this is a name commonly used by developers out there, which has caused applications to break all over the place when upgrading. I forget which version has this class but I think it starts with 4.5.2.

What you want to do is downgrade your .NET version to whatever the version was before the System.AppContext class was introduced (presumably 4.5.1).

Comment: System.AppContext was introduced in version 4.6 (see version information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)